# Set shortcut icon with path and icon index

Tags: icons, shortcut

If I create a shortcut and:

1. Right mouse click
2. Properties
3. <kbd>Shortcut Tab</kbd>
4. <kbd>Change Icon...</kbd>

---

#### Which brings me here

[image: Change Icon UI]

#### And enter in the edit box

`%SystemRoot%\System32\Shell32.dll,1`.

#### It throws this error

[image: Error message]

---

#### Question

Is it possible to point to a supported [icon file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) along with its `index` like so:
`%SystemRoot%\System32\Shell32.dll,1` which is throwing that error shown above.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: I checked other similar questions and it was tagged like that. I'll remove it then.

Comment: I meant, why is this on Stackoverflow? Seems more like a Superuser question if you ask me.

Comment: I suppose I could delete it. I don't mind.

Comment: It can be migrated.

Comment: Perfect, sorry for the trouble. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `,1` suffix is the icon index, not an ID. Just pick the second icon in the dialog (the first icon is index 0). Icons are listed top-to-bottom, left-to-right, the icon you want is the document with the "A" on it.

The `,1` suffix syntax is used in the registry and other places and the [`PathParseIconLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathparseiconlocationa) function is used to parse those paths. The icon picker dialog does not support those paths, you must specify the file path without the suffix and select the icon manually.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I suppose once I just pick the icon it's baked into the shortcut anyway? I'll modify my answer to change ID to index.

Comment: No, the icon image data is not stored inside the shortcut, it just stores the path and index.

Comment: Yes, I was refering to that. Thanks.